# How do you search for null values in a case statements in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a case statement in which I'd like to handle null values. I've done various tests and think this should work, however it does not.

The user 12345 does not have any clicks, but it returns 20plus rather than none in this case statement. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
select count(inid2), sum(clickcount) as Clicks,
CASE clickcount when clickcount=1 then '1'
when clickcount>=2 and clickcount<=5 then '2to5'
when clickcount>=6 and clickcount<=10 then '6to10'
when clickcount>=11 and clickcount<=20 then '11 to 20'
when coalesce (clickcount, 0) =0 then 'none'
else '20plus' 
END as clickbuckets
from reportingsandbox.clicktest3
where inid2 = '12345'
group by clickbuckets
```

Comment: It's not clear why this isn't working (other than the syntax error). Please post full code with no syntax error as well as test data.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. (I can't figure out what you're trying to do...)

Comment: I wanted to bucket users based on the number of clicks. (including nulls). The syntax error was the only issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the `CASE` expression this way:

```
select count(inid2), sum(clickcount) as Clicks,
       CASE  
          when clickcount=1 then '1'
          when clickcount>=2 and clickcount<=5 then '2to5'
          when clickcount>=6 and clickcount<=10 then '6to10'
          when clickcount>=11 and clickcount<=20 then '11 to 20'
          when coalesce (clickcount, 0) =0 then 'none'
          else '20plus' 
       END as clickbuckets
from reportingsandbox.clicktest3
where inid2 = '12345'
group by clickbuckets
```

Comment: Can postgresql mix clickcount an SUM(clickcount) like that?

Comment: While the OP had a syntax error in what they posted, Postgres would have told them about that, so I suspect that's not the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Removing the first clickcount in the case worked. I was only ever testing with 1 user, which is why it worked for others (I think)